# Center Content of CSS Grid

Tags: css, layout, grid

struggling here with a CSS Grid that should consist of 7 squares per row to build a calendar style layout. Layout seems to be okay, but I cannot center the title and subtitle in the middle of the item. I tried margin:auto and vertical-align:middle, wrapper span or div to align the h1/h2 inside there. Please see working example below with text sticking to the top of the item.

Any suggestion is very welcome!

fj

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        
        *{
            color: white;
        }
        
        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-gap: 1px;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
        }

        .grid-item {
            background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/787961/pexels-photo-787961.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            text-align: center;
            align-content: center;
            height: 14vw;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-item" style="position: relative;align-content:center">
                <span style="align-content:center; vertical-align: middle; margin: auto">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 13px">title</h1>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 11px">subtitle</h2>    
                </span>
                <span style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">Mo, 21.09.</span>
                <span style="position: absolute; top: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">x</span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="grid-item" style="position: relative;align-content:center">
                <span style="align-content:center; vertical-align: middle; margin: auto">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 13px">title</h1>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 11px">subtitle</h2>    
                </span>
                <span style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">Mo, 21.09.</span>
                <span style="position: absolute; top: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">x</span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="grid-item" style="position: relative;align-content:center">
                <span style="align-content:center; vertical-align: middle; margin: auto">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 13px">title</h1>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 11px">subtitle</h2>    
                </span>
                <span style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">Mo, 21.09.</span>
                <span style="position: absolute; top: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">x</span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="grid-item" style="position: relative;align-content:center">
                <span style="align-content:center; vertical-align: middle; margin: auto">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 13px">title</h1>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 11px">subtitle</h2>    
                </span>
                <span style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">Mo, 21.09.</span>
                <span style="position: absolute; top: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">x</span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="grid-item" style="position: relative;align-content:center">
                <span style="align-content:center; vertical-align: middle; margin: auto">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 13px">title</h1>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 11px">subtitle</h2>    
                </span>
                <span style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">Mo, 21.09.</span>
                <span style="position: absolute; top: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">x</span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="grid-item" style="position: relative;align-content:center">
                <span style="align-content:center; vertical-align: middle; margin: auto">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 13px">title</h1>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 11px">subtitle</h2>    
                </span>
                <span style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">Mo, 21.09.</span>
                <span style="position: absolute; top: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">x</span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="grid-item" style="position: relative;align-content:center">
                <span style="align-content:center; vertical-align: middle; margin: auto">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 13px">title</h1>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 11px">subtitle</h2>    
                </span>
                <span style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">Mo, 21.09.</span>
                <span style="position: absolute; top: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">x</span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="grid-item" style="position: relative;align-content:center">
                <span style="align-content:center; vertical-align: middle; margin: auto">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 13px">title</h1>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 11px">subtitle</h2>    
                </span>
                <span style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">Mo, 21.09.</span>
                <span style="position: absolute; top: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">x</span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="grid-item" style="position: relative;align-content:center">
                <span style="align-content:center; vertical-align: middle; margin: auto">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 13px">title</h1>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 11px">subtitle</h2>    
                </span>
                <span style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">Mo, 21.09.</span>
                <span style="position: absolute; top: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">x</span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="grid-item" style="position: relative;align-content:center">
                <span style="align-content:center; vertical-align: middle; margin: auto">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 13px">title</h1>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 11px">subtitle</h2>    
                </span>
                <span style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">Mo, 21.09.</span>
                <span style="position: absolute; top: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">x</span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="grid-item" style="position: relative;align-content:center">
                <span style="align-content:center; vertical-align: middle; margin: auto">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 13px">title</h1>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 11px">subtitle</h2>    
                </span>
                <span style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">Mo, 21.09.</span>
                <span style="position: absolute; top: 10px;right: 10px;font-size: 0.8vw;font-weight: 700">x</span>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: grid` or `display: flex` to the `.grid-item` class.

[image]

The web inspector in Firefox actually provides the answer directly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy, this was waaaay easier then expected!